# How do I efficiently get data from a database as soon as it updates?

Tags: c#, mysql

So, I'm trying to get data from a database as soon as it appears in there. I'm currently accomplishing this by having a timer execute each second with a select query that gets the desired information. But by doing this it makes the program lag pretty hard each second, so it looks really bad.

My question is, is there a better way of getting data as soon as the database updates? Or is there maybe a better way to optimize the way I'm doing this so it doesn't create lagspikes each second?

```
private void updateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mySqlConnection = "<connection_string>"; //left out for security purposes
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mySqlConnection);

    List<String> id = new List<String>();
    List<String> source = new List<String>();
    List<String> message = new List<String>();

    using (connection)
    {
        connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT id, source, message FROM Table WHERE target = @address";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", ipAddress);

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            id.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            source.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            message.Add(reader.GetString(2));
        }

        command.Parameters.Clear();

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only check if a table has been updated you can do this:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS like 'tablename';
```

and then you have to find the update field:

```
if (dr.Read()) 
{ 
  if (dr["Update_time"] != null || dr["Update_time"] != System.DBNull.Value)
  { 
    result = (DateTime) dr["Update_time"]; 
  } 
}
```

Compare this to the last result you got to see if they differ.

This should be less intensive on the DB and application.

Comment: I tried replacing my SELECT query with SHOW TABLE STATUS, but that doesn't seem to make a difference in terms of how much it taxes my application. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using WinForms or WPF. The timer should be in a separate thread to minimize the impact on the GUI thread. That would make the application more responsive and the database check wouldn't even be noticed by the user.

Comment: Sounds perfect, could you give me a step in the right direction for making a separate thread? That stuff is kinda new for me.

Comment: Check out [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help man! Using a BackgroundWorker fixed the lagspikes I'd been getting and makes everything look smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb for using a database as a messaging queue.

1) Don't use the actual data table. Use a separate, dedicated, fast access table to hold messages. The polling process should be able to query this in millisecond response time. You can either change your other code to manually insert/update the queue table, or implement a trigger on the main table to update the queue table. The key is to keep the queue table fast and independent of potentially slow transactions on the "master".

2) If it isn't required that your messages be persistent in the database, consider using a cheap, fast, in-memory database like Redis to distribute messages.

3) Or use a separate reliable queueing mechanism. There are various frameworks out there. I believe MySQL even has one.

Comment: Is what you mention in your first point possible in a regular mysql database? I'm pretty confident I'm indeed using the data table right now, but I'm not sure what you mean with a separate, dedicated fast access table in relation to mysql. Or do I need a system like Redis to accomplis that?

Comment: I meant the process of notifying your data consumer as quickly as possible. You would then run your regular query to grab the data, but that would be only when you knew data was ready. The polling process would only do a fast query on a messaging table. Consider a MAILBOX table with a row per table that tells your program "table X has new data at 12:32AM".

Comment: My table is fairly empty either way because I don't keep the data around after it has been retrieved. I ended up using a BackgroundWorker as Sani Huttunen advised me, but thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a chat program not long ago and was faced with the same question.

My solution was rather different but it's up to you if you will like it.

Since it was fairly small network where I implemented it at, and since workstations already have a chat program in them, I use a socket listener for the client via UDP and created a socket shout from the db server everytime the db is updated. No need for timers.